# Why does finding only one particular solution yield the general solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently working with linear differential equations, but I lack some very foundational understanding for why they are solved certain ways. Suppose we have a simple equation, such as:

$y'-2y=8x$

To find the general solution, we need to find the homogenous solution to the equation and one particular solution. I understand why, becuase of linearity, if $y_c$ is a solution to the homogenous equation, then $y_c+y_p$ will be a solution to the non-homogenous equation. But how come we only need to find *one* particular solution? Won't the one we choose change our answer?

One particular solution to the equation above would be $y=-4x-2$. But we could easily find another particular solution using the integrating factor $e^{-2x}$. That would yield a particular solution: $y=-2e^{-2x}(2x+1)+C$. So now we have two possible solutions that look widely different to me:

$y=C_1e^{-2x}-4x-2$

$y=C_1e^{-2x}-2e^{-2x}(2x+1)+C_2$

I guess my questions are:

1. Are both of these the same general solution?
2. Why do we only need to find *one* particular solution to find the general solution?

EDIT: I should add I have been reading some threads on here, but none of the answers that I came across were satisfactory to me.

Comment: You need to divide your second solution by $e^{-2x}$.  That matches the first one because it should have $C_1e^{2x}$ instead of $C_1e^{-2x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about second order linear ODEs, like
$$\ddot{y}-3\dot{y}+2y=2$$
then it is possible for combining a homogenous solution with two different particular solutions to give two different answers.

E.g. take $y_c=e^x$ as the homogenus solution and $y_1=1$ and $y_2=1+e^{2x}$ as the particular solutions. Using $y_1$ we get
$$y=1+Ae^x$$
and using $y_2$ we get
$$y=1+e^{2x}+Ce^x$$
These are two genuinely different answers. But the reason this is able to happen is that neither of them are full answers.

You'll notice that if both of these are solutions, then their difference $y=e^{2x}$ must be a solution to the homogenous equation, and one that we missed to start with. If we include this, to get the full solution to the homogenous equation
$$y_c=Ae^x+Be^{2x}$$
then we get the same answer whether we use $y_1$ or $y_2$:

$y_1$ gives us
$$y=1+Ae^x+Be^{2x}$$
and $y_2$ gives us
$$y=1+e^{2x}+Ce^x+De^{2x}=1+Ce^x+(D+1)e^{2x}$$
which you can see are the same.

What's happened here is that as long as the difference between our particular solutions ($e^{2x}$) is included in our homogenous solution, then by adding some multiple of our homogenous solution we'll be able to get from one particular solution to the other. This means $y_2=y_c+y_1$ for some homogenous solution $y_c$ and vice versa, so $y_2$ gets included in our answer, even though we used $y_1$ to make our answer.

$y_2$ and $y_1$ are the same as each other up to a multiple of the homogenous solution so when we add in the homogenous solution, they give us the same thing. We'll have an extra copy of (in this case) $e^{2x}$ for one of them, but because we're already including $De^{2x}$ in our solution, this just turns $De^{2x}$ into $(D+1)e^{2x}$, which doesn't affect anything. It could only affect anything if we forgot to include the $De^{2x}$.

And the difference $y_2-y_1$ between our particular solutions will always be a homogenous solution, so as long as we got all of the homogenous solutions to start with, we know $y_1$ and $y_2$ will be the same up to multiples of the homogenous solutions we've already found.

The other way to think about it is if $y_1$ and $y_2$ weren't the same up to multiples of the homogenous solutions we've already found, $y_2-y_1$ would be another homogenous solution that we've missed.

For the first order linear ODEs that you're dealing with, there will always only be one homogenous solution (up to a scalar multiple) so as long as you have any nonzero homogenous solution, you know you have all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the integrating factor to get
$$
(e^{-2x}y)'=e^{-2x}(8x),
$$
then the integration preserves that factor on the left side, so you get
$$
e^{-2x}y(x)=-2e^{-2x}(2x+1)+C
$$
Isolating the solution gives
$$
y(x)=-2(2x+1)+Ce^{2x},
$$
so that you gain nothing new over the solution from the first method.